# Spring Integration auto reconnect to IBM MQ

Tags: spring-integration, ibm-mq

I am using Spring Integration to connect to IBM MQ. I have a flow where I received a message from inbound Queue and if any error occurred message will moved to error queue. 
What if my application is up and IBM MQ goes down does my service will still run or it will throw any error? Does Spring Integration reconnect again if IBM MQ started without restarting server?
I think there is a recoveryInterval parameter DefaultMessageListenerContainer class that will try to recover if MQ connection break. Is my understanding correct?

Thanks
Sachin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will keep trying to reconnect; be sure to use `acknowledge=transacted` (or `setSessionTransacted(true)`) with the DMLC to avoid losing messages.

Comment: Yes that does the trick. Thanks. we have acknowledge=transacted for DMLC. What if message process is in progress and MQ goes down and message has some error that should go into error Queue but as MQ down it does not send the message into error Queue. We tried this scenario and message has lost. I thought the message will go into inbound queue or once MQ up it will go into error Queue but it seems doenst worked in that way. How do we handle above scenerio?

Comment: You need to be sure that the listener container thread does not hand off the message to another thread; if it does, the message will be removed at that point. If you keep everything on the container thread, if the broker goes down, the in-flight message will be rolled back.

Comment: How do I confirm that the message is hand off to another thread? I am totally rely on container thread.

Comment: Thanks Gary It solved the problem. recoveryInterval keep trying to reconnect . Is there anyway I can configure to reconnect to MQ twice only and if same problem occur then stop the inbound adapter?